# Documentation - Split edits by example rather than topic

Tags: feature-request, documentation

Should documentation edits be considered on a per-example basis rather than a per-topic one? It seems rather non-intuitive to be editing a specific example in a topic and be bombarded with notifications about other users making edits to different parts of a topic which are not related to the edit you are currently making.

Comment: Additionally, I've seen a number of proposals where multiple examples are edited, and some *are* quality, but I reject the whole darn thing because some just... *aren't*.

Comment: And on top of the last comment, you can't have multiple separate edits. Ie you can't edit one example and then go and edit another example as they will be combined into a single edit.