# New Topic examples should not lock the entire Topic for edit

Tags: feature-request, documentation

If you add a new example to a Topic, you lose the ability to make edits or changes to existing examples.

Perhaps there is a technical reason why this is the case, but this really reduces the ability of the user to provide improvements to other examples until the new example has been approved.

The feature request is that adding a new example does not lock out the user from making changes to other parts of the Topic.

Comment: You should be able to add more than one example in the same edit, though. Is that not the case?

Comment: Yes you can add multiple examples in the one edit.  But it locks you out from editing existing answers (by you or other users) until the current edit is approved.

Comment: What I mean is: in the same edit, you should be able to edit or delete existing examples, _and_ add new examples.

Comment: And if you realize you want to further edit anything after you've already proposed an edit, you can retract it and edit further. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/documentation-proposed-changes)

Comment: Sure you can do that, but what if the edits are unrelated?  Wouldn't you think it better to have unrelated changes in different edits?  Otherwise, an edit may have to be rejected because of one part of an edit, even though all other parts are fine.  The other option being, the user waits for the existing edit to be accepted and comes back at some later date to make the next edit.

Comment: In that case, unless I misread something, your post is a duplicate of [this one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/328559/1328704), right?

Comment: Indeed, it seems so, though their gripe is about the notification spam

Comment: I've closed it as such, then — you're both pointing out the same thing, even if it's for different reasons.