# Documentation should be editable by section

Tags: feature-request, bug, documentation

Edits should be in one section / example, not the entire topic. Adding a link to remarks shouldn't conflict with a change that's changing a single example.

There's already [another thread to split edits only for examples](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/328559/documentation-split-edits-by-example-rather-than-topic), but I think it makes sense to extend that to split everything into as small units as possible.

Additionally, this topic is marked as bug, because editing different parts is really not conflicting but is marked as such.

Comment: I'd agree with this.  I also think it should make it easier to crosslink entries so they can be displaied in multiple groups but wlll be displayed/edited the same in all locations at to not create confusion.  An an example would be the `C# keywords` list and the `C# 6.0 Extensions`.

Answer (score 3):

[Being the third one asking a similar question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/328734/4347580), I actually got an answer.

The idea is that the whole page is consumed. So much for *why* it is that way.

I totally agree to the proposal to **make editing more granular**. Another use case for that is: If somebody adds two examples to a topic and I want to reject one but approve the other, I'm stuck. It's all or nothing.

Applying this to all sections appears to be the most reasonable approach.