# Are documentation edits per topic or per example/remark/etc.?

Tags: support, documentation

I was under the impression that editing an example means I only edit that.

But it looks like editing another example or the remarks etc. of the topic contributes to one single draft of mine.

From Q&A I'm used to editing only the question or only one answer, but not everything as a whole.

Are there problems if two people edit different parts the same time?
Are all drafts merged?

**Wouldn't it make more sense to have a more granular concept of edits, so that only the example is edited, or the syntax, etc...?**

Answer (score -5, accepted):

Drafts are merged if possible.

We group edits into topics because people are not consuming individual sections, they're looking at the whole page.  Additionally, the non-example sections of a topic should build on the examples - so there's another level of relations.

Most of the more advanced edit options (moving examples, rolling back, changing topic level versions) also only make sense in the context of an entire topic.

Basically things are much saner if we always consider a whole page, but do our best to merge multiple edits.

Comment: As a user I don't agree here. Moving examples and changing top level versions can happen when one edits the general / initial section.

Comment: "Most of the more advanced edit options (moving examples, rolling back, changing topic level versions) also only make sense in the context of an entire topic." Really? I don't believe it. There is not much interaction between examples and remarks. It makes sense to scope edits to subsection of topics if possible. So I don't really understand that.

Comment: *people are not consuming individual sections*... Which people are you talking about? I thought the idea was that people would search, find an example of what they want, and use the example in their own code. If I got to the page via search, why would I look at the other examples (especially, as in the case of [Strings on JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/javascript/1041/strings#t=201607281430039353918) there are 19 examples in the topic)?