# Independent edit requests in documentation

Tags: feature-request, documentation

It should probably be possible to make independent edit requests in documentation articles. It seems both confusing and inefficient for both writer and reviewer for, say, miscellaneous spelling/grammar fixes and the addition of a major section to be grouped together in the review queue.

Comment: You mean, a person who submits a Documentation change should be able to specify whether it is a "formatting" related change or a "content" related change, and then those two types of changes would be presented separately in the review queue? ...Why would this be necessary? A good change is a good change, regardless of what it fixes.

Comment: Rather, it should be possible to separate changes in general. I don't see why adding an example and adding a remark should be combined into the same edit, either. Unless you're actually editing the same text twice, there's no particular reason to combine them I don't think.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Documentation should be editable by section](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/328692/documentation-should-be-editable-by-section) and http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/328559/documentation-split-edits-by-example-rather-than-topic. See also: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/330342/allow-us-to-roll-back-a-documentation-example-not-just-an-entire-topic